# Tiny parts of Windows 10 not changed after switching language

Tags: windows-10, language

There are a dozen of threads about this topic, but my specific problem seems to be different.

My problem started after I had accidently added German to the languages under Settings -> Language and applied it with a restart:

[Screenshot of display languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRWcW.png)

Now I just want to go back to English as it was before. Unfortunately, even after removing German from that list, some tiny parts of the OS still show in German. First thing is not a real issue: while the welcome screen is English as expected, I can shorty read "Willkommen" (German for "Welcome") after I have entered my password. This alone would not be a problem. The nasty thing is that the account names of built-in users are still referenced in German (while all group names etc. are English as desired):

[Screnshot showing wrong language for built-in users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHg8M.png)

This prevents me to execute some .msi installers that look for the SID of a built-in account using the English name.

What I have already tried to solve the problem:

- Selecting different English language packs (e.g. US and UK)
- Adding German again, making it the Display language, removing it again
- Go to old Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative

  - "Copy Settings" (to apply English-only profile to System accounts and Welcome Screen)
  - "Change System Locale"
- Use a Restore Point

  - Unfortunately there was no Restore Point for a time when everything was fine, so I just tried a different one
  - **It still was a temporary success:** After the System came up again after restore, I was greeted with "Welcome" instead of "Willkommen" after I signed in with my regular user. Also, all the account names where English again. But the problem came back from alone. After the next restart I was again greeted with "Willkommen". Account names where still English, though. But another restart later also account names switched back to German.
- Checked the installed language using `Get-WinUserLanguageList` from PowerShell (but everything is fine)

I'm out of ideas now. Only thing that's left would be a system reset or using "sysprep" as described for a similar problem here: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/72642-windows-language-not-completely-changed.html. But I assume that would kick my PC out of the company domain (what I'd like to avoid, because it could be hard to get support during these Corona times).

Any other ideas?

**Update 1:**

As suggested in the comments I executed `Get-computerinfo | FL OsLanguage,OSMUIlanguages, OsLocale` in the PowerShell. It shows me the following:

```
OsLanguage     : en-US
OsMuiLanguages : {en-US, de-DE, en-GB}
OsLocale       : en-US
```

Note the `de-DE` under OsMuiLanguages. How could I get rid of that?

Comment: You could check/edit the language list via Powershell https://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-remove-language-pack-windows-10

Comment: Run the following in PowerShell: `Get-computerinfo | FL OsLanguage,OSMUIlanguages, OsLocale`  I assume your OsLanguage is de-DE which is why built-in users and groups are listed in English. As far as I know you can not change the OsLanguage after installation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated the question accordingly. @PeterHahndorf, your suggestion seem to show something interesting. OsLanguage is `en-US`, but OsMuiLanguages contains a `de-DE` entry.

Comment: With OSLanguage `en-US` I would assume `(Get-LocalGroup -SID S-1-5-32-544).Name` returns `Administrators` not `Administratoren` is this not the case?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?